# Masonry v3.0.4 resizing

Tags: jquery, resize

I'm upgrading my site from Masonry 2 to Masonry 3.

In Masonry 2, I was using

```
$(window).bind('smartresize.masonry', function() {
 //recalculate my container width
});
```

On this page http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html#upgrading-from-v2
They say "smartresize jQuery plugin has been removed" without more explanation.

smartresize.masonry was perfect to me, it allowed me to recalculate my container width and masonry fit in this new width without delay.

Now with v3, I'm doing:

```
container.masonry('bindResize');

$(window).resize(function() {
 //recalculate my container width
});
```

These are 2 separate events and there's a small delay between the 2 of them.
It seems that bindResize is not called with the same frequency as $(window).resize(), am I wrong?

Is there a way to do exactly what smartresize was doing?

Comment: Do you have almost a solution for this problem. When I resize, there will be big spaces and overlapping elements, even when I use imagesLoaded plugin. Like to hear from you. @Bractar

Answer (score 0):

The bad part with this new Masonry, is that there's no something like onBeforeResize and onAfterResize. 
I installed the plugin smartresize (debouncedresize) and disabled Masonry's resizing event 
container.masonry('unbindResize');
Then I refresh the Masonry's layout inside my own resizing function.